# When uploading an archive with a project to React Native in AppStore via XCode 14.1, a many errors occurs

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store

[image]Example Error: Invalid image path - No image found at the path referenced under key CFBundleIcon AppIcon20x20

And there are many such mistakes.